# "undefined method" when using Capybara without any framework

Tags: ruby, capybara

I'd want to use Capybara in plain Ruby without Rails, Cucumber, Rspec, Test::Unit, etc. for debugging purposes. I configured it as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172889/841064) but I still have exceptions when using Capybara API.

```
require 'rspec'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'rspec/expectations'

Capybara.app_host = "http://somedomain.com"
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium

include Capybara::DSL

visit '/'
page.should have_xpath "//span[@class='my_class']"
```

`visit` method works fine. But I have exception `undefined method 'have_xpath' for main:Object`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use RSpec matchers without including them:

```
include RSpec::Matchers
```